# Using Microsoft Release Management to Deploy Azure Cloud Services

Tags: azure, release-management, ms-release-management

Is there any published guidance for using Release Management (formerly InCycle's InRelease) to deploy Azure Cloud Services?

Specifically, I'm interesting in the agent license issues (as you're deploying not via an agent on the machine but via a packaged cloud deployment) as well as dealing with the fact that the normal token-based replacement of items in the web.config would be a challenge.

Comment: Microsoft released an agentless pipeline with Release Management update 3 that helps you deploy azure cloud services without going through Deployment Agent installation. Have a look at this link - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/07/07/how-to-deploy-to-standard-or-azure-environments-in-release-management-2013-with-update-3-rc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following links should be helpful:

http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2013/02/deploy-automatically-on-a-virtual-machine-in-windows-azure/
http://support.inreleasesoftware.com/entries/21683466-InRelease-configuration-for-Windows-Azure-Service-deployment

Comment: For working with multiple domains :http://support.inreleasesoftware.com/entries/21926057-requirements-for-multiple-domains

Comment: If any further queries, post them to release management forum. Release Management team is monitoring it. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: I see that Update 2 was just released, but I'm not seeing anything new with cloud service deployments. Any links?